# C++ uses twice the memory when moving elements from one dequeue to another

Tags: python, c++, out-of-memory, python-asyncio, pybind11

In my project, I use [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) to bind C++ code to Python. Recently I have had to deal with very large data sets (70GB+) and encountered need to split data from one `std::deque` between multiple `std::deque`'s. Since my dataset is so large, I expect the split not to have much of memory overhead. Therefore I went for one pop - one push strategy, which in general should ensure that my requirements are met.

That is all in theory. In practice, my process got killed. So I struggled for past two days and eventually came up with following minimal example demonstrating the problem.

Generally the minimal example creates bunch of data in `deque` (~11GB), returns it to Python, then calls again to `C++` to move the elements. Simple as that. Moving part is done in executor.

The interesting thing is, that if I don't use executor, memory usage is as expected and also when limits on virtual memory by ulimit are imposed, the program really respects these limits and doesn't crash.

**test.py**

```
from test import _test
import asyncio
import concurrent

async def test_main(loop, executor):
    numbers = _test.generate()
    # moved_numbers = _test.move(numbers) # This works!
    moved_numbers = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, _test.move, numbers) # This doesn't!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)

    task = loop.create_task(test_main(loop, executor))
    loop.run_until_complete(task)

    executor.shutdown()
    loop.close()
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::deque<uint64_t>);
PYBIND11_DECLARE_HOLDER_TYPE(T, std::shared_ptr<T>);

template<class T>
void py_bind_opaque_deque(py::module& m, const char* type_name) {
    py::class_<std::deque<T>, std::shared_ptr<std::deque<T>>>(m, type_name)
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def(py::init<size_t, T>());
}

PYBIND11_PLUGIN(_test) {
    namespace py = pybind11;
    pybind11::module m("_test");
    py_bind_opaque_deque<uint64_t>(m, "NumbersDequeue");

    // Generate ~11Gb of data.
    m.def("generate", []() {
        std::deque<uint64_t> numbers;
        for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 1500 * 1000000; ++i) {
            numbers.push_back(i);
        }
        return numbers;
    });

    // Move data from one dequeue to another.
    m.def("move", [](std::deque<uint64_t>& numbers) {
        std::deque<uint64_t> numbers_moved;

        while (!numbers.empty()) {
            numbers_moved.push_back(std::move(numbers.back()));
            numbers.pop_back();
        }
        std::cout << "Done!\n";
        return numbers_moved;
    });

    return m.ptr();
}
```

**test/__init__.py**

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("default")
```

**Compilation**:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -march=native -fPIC -Iextern/pybind11 `python3.5-config --includes` `python3.5-config --ldflags` `python3.5-config --libs` -shared -o test/_test.so test.cpp
```

**Observations:**

- When the moving part is not done by executor, so we just call `moved_numbers = _test.move(numbers)`, all works as expected, memory usage showed by htop stays around `11Gb`, great!.
- When moving part is done in executor, the program takes double the memory and crashes.
- When limits on virtual memory are introduced (~15Gb), all works fine, which is probably the most interesting part.

  `ulimit -Sv 15000000 && python3.5 test.py` >> `Done!`.
- When we increase the limit the program crashes (150Gb > my RAM).

  `ulimit -Sv 150000000 && python3.5 test.py` >> `[1]    2573 killed     python3.5 test.py`
- Usage of deque method `shrink_to_fit` doesn't help (And nor it should)

**Used software**

```
Ubuntu 14.04
gcc version 5.4.1 20160904 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~14.04)
Python 3.5.2
pybind11 latest release - v1.8.1
```

**Note**

Please note that this example was made merely to demonstrate the problem. Usage of `asyncio` and `pybind` is necessary for problem to occur.

Any ideas on what might be going on are most welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be caused by Data being created in one thread and then deallocated in another one. It is so because of malloc arenas in glibc [(for reference see this)](https://siddhesh.in/posts/malloc-per-thread-arenas-in-glibc.html). It can be nicely demonstrated by doing:

```
executor1 = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
executor2 = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)

numbers = await loop.run_in_executor(executor1, _test.generate)
moved_numbers = await loop.run_in_executor(executor2, _test.move, numbers)
```

which would take twice the memory allocated by `_test.generate` and

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(1)

numbers = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, _test.generate)
moved_numbers = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, _test.move, numbers)
```

which wound't.

This issue can be solved either by rewriting the code so it doesn't move the elements from one container to another (my case) or by setting environment variable `export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=1` which will limit number of malloc arenas to 1. This however might have some performance implications involved (There is a good reason for having multiple arenas).